# Query criteria base on form check box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to run the following as criteria in an MS access query. Basically what I want to do is:

- If checkbox (Check0) = True and (Check2) = False, then only records that match the value "HighSc" in Field "ScType" are shown. or otherwise value "Town" in Field "Location" are shown.
- If checkbox (Check0) and (Check2) = True then records that match the value "HighSc" in Field "ScType" and value "Town" in Field "Location" are shown. All match value from both field should be shown.
- If all checkbox = False then all records from all Field are shown.

My current expression doesn't give a expected results...Here my **Field** *expression*,

Table "tblSourceB"

```
ID KODSEK   SET1   SET2
1  A001     1       3
2  A002     2       4
3  A003     4       3
4  A004     4       6
5  A005     5       12
6  A006     4       23
7  A234     3       98
```

Table "ScProfil"

```
ID ScCode  SUB   ScType  Location 
1  A001   SEK31  HighSc   
2  A002   SEK82          Town
3  A003   SEK43  HighSc  Town
4  A004   SEK23          Town
5  A005   SEK21  HighSc  Town
6  A006   SEK65          
7  A234   SEK12
```

My Query

```
SELECT tblSourceB.KODSEK, ScProfil.ScType, ScProfil.Location
FROM tblSourceB LEFT JOIN ScProfil ON tblSourceB.KODSEK = ScProfil.ScCode
WHERE (((ScProfil.ScType) Like IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Check0]=True,"HighSc","*")) 
AND ((ScProfil.Location) Like IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Check2]=True,"Town","*")));
```

Either checkbox one or both is select or deselect, the result shown only "A003" and "A005" at column "KODSEK"
If I change "AND" to "OR", either checkbox one or both is select or deselect, the result shown "A003, A002, A003, A004, A005" and "A005" at column "KODSEK".

Comment: What results does it give you that are unexpected?  Provide a set of sample data and the results that you do expect.  Have you tried 0 and -1 instead of True and False?

Comment: Update the sample data and result. "0" and "1" also not working.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I have this same question.